# Google BigQuery: "An internal error occurred..." during basic query

Tags: google-bigquery

I followed a very basic setup to load data into BigQuery and so far it seems that every query fails with "An internal error occurred and the request could not be completed."

Here's the process I used:

1. Generate a CSV containing data in the following format:

   `1475159092288, 112194, 112196
   1475159091885, 112195, 112196
   1475159091776, 112195, 112198
   1475159091689, 112195, 112196`
2. Upload the CSV to Google drive
3. Create a new table using Google Drive as the source: https://ameo.link/u/3sy.png
4. Run a query on the generated table such as the example query: `SELECT tick_time FROM [tick-data-analysis:EURUSD_partial.ticks] LIMIT 100;`

The error message is then returned with no additional information provided about its cause.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that since the Google Drive account hosting the data I was trying to import was from different from the account on which I was using BigQuery, BigQuery was unable to import the data set (despite me setting the sharing settings to public and providing a valid link).

To solve the problem, I shared the item with the BigQuery account and was able to upload it successfully.